# Checking if entry in txt file exists in imported txt file

Tags: c#

I thought this was a fairly straight forward piece of code, i have a .txt file called: `template-success.txt` which just contains entries like:

```
article|url.com
article|url.com
article|url.org
article|url.org
```

```
    private void BtnImportDomains_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = @"Text files|*.txt";
        ofd.Title = @"Select your url file ...";
        ofd.FileName = "urls.txt";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return;
        }

        var sites = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"py-templates\template-success.txt");

        foreach (string site in sites)
        {
            if (!lines.Contains(site))
            {
                dataGridViewMain.Rows.Add(TrimToRoot(site));
            } 
        }
    }
```

So when i import a new .txt file i was checking to see if one of the lines in the `template-success.txt` file contains the same domain, if it is already in the main file do not add it to the datagrid, the code above adds all imported urls and doesn't seem to check if they exist or not before adding, but looking at the code i don't see anything wrong, have i over looked something simple, any help is appreciated.

Comment: `lines` is a string[] array, not a string. Thus, `lines.Contains(someString)` checks whether this string array posesses a string that is equal to _someString_. Do you see how your code works and how what you think it does is not what it actually is doing?

Comment: Side note: Pay attention that not some of your `site` strings accidentally appear in the "article" portion of the lines from template-success.txt, as this will completely screw up the logic you are trying to implement here...

Answer (score 0):

`lines.Contains()` will only return `true` if there's a whole line that exactly matches `site`.  You need to iterate through the lines, and for each line see if `line.Contains(site)`.

Alternatively you could read the whole file into a single string, that would work.

```
var wholeFile = File.ReadAllText(@"py-templates\template-success.txt");
foreach (string site in sites)
{
    if (!wholeFile.Contains(site))
    {
        dataGridViewMain.Rows.Add(TrimToRoot(site));
    } 
}
```

I'd also watch out for some common gotchas, like case-sensitivity, extra whitespace etc.

Comment: Added more code to clarify.  But this would work and accomplish OP's goal.

Comment: My bad, you are right (and i was wrong). For a moment i falsely believed OP wanted to add the lines from template-success.txt to the GridView. Complete brain freeze, i am sorry...